# Maven API search doesn't retrieve Google dependcies

Tags: java, android, maven, sonatype

When I use Maven API search function it works fine with dependencies in Central repo (e.g. retrofit), however, it doesn't retrieve dependencies from Google repo (e.g. play-services-plus). Even though they both available in the web search https://mvnrepository.com.

###### Retrofit

- Web Search Results: 
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.8.2
- API URL: 
  [API Link](https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:%22com.squareup.retrofit2%22%20AND%20a:%22retrofit%22%20AND%20v:%222.8.2%22)
- API Results: 
  `{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"g:\"com.squareup.retrofit2\" AND a:\"retrofit\" AND v:\"2.8.2\"","core":"","indent":"off","fl":"id,g,a,v,p,ec,timestamp,tags","start":"","sort":"score desc,timestamp desc,g asc,a asc,v desc","rows":"20","wt":"json","version":"2.2"}},"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[{"id":"com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.2","g":"com.squareup.retrofit2","a":"retrofit","v":"2.8.2","p":"jar","timestamp":1589829834000,"ec":["-sources.jar","-javadoc.jar",".jar",".pom"],"tags":["safe","client","android","http","java","type"]}]}}`

###### Play Services Plus

- Web Search Results: 
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-plus/16.0.0
- API URL: 
  [API Link For Google Services](https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:%22com.google.android.gms%22%20AND%20a:%22play-services-plus%22%20AND%20v:%2216.0.0%22)
- API Results: 
  `{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":0,"params":{"q":"g:\"com.google.android.gms\" AND a:\"play-services-plus\" AND v:\"16.0.0\"","core":"","indent":"off","fl":"id,g,a,v,p,ec,timestamp,tags","start":"","sort":"score desc,timestamp desc,g asc,a asc,v desc","rows":"20","wt":"json","version":"2.2"}},"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}}`

How to retrieve dependencies outside Central repo, I need to make this programmatically e.g. API?

Comment: `search.maven.org` is only for Maven Central. `mvnrepository.com` is an independent service, and its creators have elected to index more Maven repositories than just Maven Central.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare for the info. Is their an alternative for `search.maven.org` for other repos e.g. Google?

Comment: Sorry, but I have never looked for one.

Comment: @Abd, Updated answer below in regards to be able to programmatically search 'Google's Maven Repository'

Comment: @djmonki, please check my comment on your answer

Comment: @Abd, updated answer below, with what you can get, you won't get any more than that from Google's Maven repo, I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks @djmonki, I accepted your answer since its sufficient, is there a way to get release date? when the version was published

Comment: Unfortunately not, that is the current limit of information that Google's Maven repo provides. At the moment the only place that you can get the release date is via our good friends at mvnrespository.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the Google maven repository, update your settings.xml file to include it as:

```
        <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <url>https://maven.google.com/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```

or your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

mvnrepository.com does detail where the dependency is available, if you revisit the url, it does  detail it just above the 'Compile Dependencies' section
[image: screenshot, with repo detail outlined in red]

To programmatically search '***Google's Maven Repository***', you can search the group-index.xml for the artifact you are looking for via `https://maven.google.com/group_path/group-index.xml`

So in your case you would search:

```
https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/group-index.xml
```

To get the release data (pom or aar) for your chosen artifact/version, you can do a GET using the following syntax: `https://maven.google.com/group_path/library/version/library-version.ext` (where ext is pom or aar)

So in your case you would do a GET for:

```
https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/16.0.0/play-services-plus-16.0.0.pom

or

https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-plus/16.0.0/play-services-plus-16.0.0.aar
```

Comment: Thank @djmonki, when I accesssed `https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/group-index.xml` I got the versions for each library. Is there a way to get the release data for each version? such as in Maven API Search

Comment: @Abd, updated answer above, with what I think you need